# how to construct vector of vector in boost interprocess

Tags: c++, boost

I'm new boost interprocess, and I've read the quick guide on [Creating vectors in shared memory](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html#interprocess.quick_guide.qg_interprocess_container). But this example only construct a `vector<int>`, in my use case I have to construct more complicated data structures (usually nested containers).

Let's take an example for `vector<vector<int>>`, I write a small example based on that quick guide

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib> //std::system
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::interprocess;

//Define an STL compatible allocator of ints that allocates from the managed_shared_memory.
//This allocator will allow placing containers in the segment
typedef allocator<int, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>  ShmemAllocator;
typedef allocator<vector<int , ShmemAllocator>, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>  ShmemAllocator2D;

//Alias a vector that uses the previous STL-like allocator so that allocates
//its values from the segment
typedef vector<int, ShmemAllocator> MyVector;
typedef vector<MyVector, ShmemAllocator2D> My2DVector;

//Main function. For parent process argc == 1, for child process argc == 2
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if(argc == 1){ //Parent process
    //Remove shared memory on construction and destruction
    struct shm_remove
    {
      shm_remove() { shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
      ~shm_remove(){ shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
    } remover;

    //Create a new segment with given name and size
    managed_shared_memory segment(create_only, "MySharedMemory", 65536);

    //Initialize shared memory STL-compatible allocator
    const ShmemAllocator2D alloc_inst (segment.get_segment_manager());

    //Construct a vector named "MyVector" in shared memory with argument alloc_inst
    My2DVector *myvector = segment.construct<My2DVector>("MyVector")(alloc_inst);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10;++i) {
      myvector->emplace_back();
//      for (int j = i; j < 10;++j) {
//        myvector->back().push_back(j);
//      }
    }

    //Launch child process
    std::string s(argv[0]); s += " child ";
    if(0 != std::system(s.c_str()))
      return 1;

    //Check child has destroyed the vector
    if(segment.find<MyVector>("MyVector").first)
      return 1;
  }
  else{ //Child process
    //Open the managed segment
    managed_shared_memory segment(open_only, "MySharedMemory");

    //Find the vector using the c-string name
    My2DVector *myvector = segment.find<My2DVector>("MyVector").first;

    //Use vector in reverse order
    for (auto &vec : *myvector){
      std::cout << "row" << std::endl;
      for (auto i:vec)
        std::cout << i << ", ";
      std::cout << std::endl;
    }


    //When done, destroy the vector from the segment
    segment.destroy<MyVector>("MyVector");
  }

  return 0;
};
```

However this code will give complie error:

```
/usr/include/boost/container/vector.hpp:301:54: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::interprocess::allocator<int, boost::interprocess::segment_manager<char, boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family>, boost::interprocess::iset_index> >::allocator()’
       : Allocator(), m_start(), m_size(), m_capacity()
```

I suppose `emplace_back` should work like stl vector....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not as simple as you may think - you initialize the outer `std::vector` with an allocator. But when using `emplace_back` to create internal `std::vector<int>` compiler tries to construct it using default constructor (which does not exist due to using shared memory allocator). I see two possible solutions.

#### Pass allocator explicitly

Instead of

```
myvector->emplace_back();
```

use

```
ShmemAllocator2D ac(segment.get_segment_manager());
myvector->emplace_back(ac);
```

for every operation adding anything to the vector. Yet, this is pretty error prone, cumbersome and there is already a known solution to this issue called:

#### [scoped_allocator_adaptor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/scoped_allocator_adaptor)

Just replace:

```
typedef allocator<vector<int , ShmemAllocator>, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>  ShmemAllocator2D;
```

with:

```
typedef scoped_allocator_adaptor<allocator<vector<int , ShmemAllocator>, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>>  ShmemAllocator2D;
```

and it should work fine